# How to identify and delete empty columns from large dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset with 1000 columns. I want to identify the empty columns and delete the complete column along with the header as a step to get rid of few unwanted variables. There are few missing values in other columns I want to retain them and delete just the columns which are completely empty. I tried the following code and did not change anything. I just got the columns with NAN's.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
  
# create a Dataframe
nan_value = float("NaN")
Mydataframe = pd.read_csv('Employee_details.csv')
Mydataframe.replace("", nan_value, inplace=False)
  
Mydataframe.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=False)
Mydataframe.to_csv(r'output.csv',index=False)
# show the dataframe
display(Mydataframe)
```

Comment: set your inplace with True value.Mydataframe.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)

Comment: @narimanzaeim Thank you for your response that is still giving me 1000 columns. Should I give add write function?

Comment: @Shourya if the problem is not solved, then show how the empty columns look when printed.

Comment: @inquirer  Thank you it actually worked  I had made a mistake in code.